# Using Promises in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I want an app where the user types an address as a query string and then receives the weather for that location as a `json` object. In the weather retrieval part, I use promises to get the latitude and longitude for the address, and then the weather. There are also options to specify the language and units.

```js
function getWeather(encodedAddress, units, language) {
    let geoKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    let geocodeURL = `http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=${geoKey}&location=${encodedAddress}`;

    return axios.get(geocodeURL).then(({data}) => {
        if (((data.results[0].locations[0].geocodeQualityCode.substring(2)).match(/X/g) || []).length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Unable to find that address')
        }
        const locationInfo = data.results[0].locations[0];
        const lat = locationInfo.latLng.lat;
        const lng = locationInfo.latLng.lng;

        console.log('Here\'s the weather for: ', locationInfo.street, locationInfo.adminArea5,
                                locationInfo.adminArea4, locationInfo.adminArea1, 
                                locationInfo.postalCode);
        
        const weatherKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        
        units = units ? `units=${units}` : 'auto';
        language = language ? `lang=${language}` :  'lang=en';
        
        const weatherURL = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${weatherKey}/${lat},${lng}?${units}&${language}`;
        return axios.get(weatherURL);

    }).then(({data}) => {
        const tempInfo = data.currently;
        const temp = tempInfo.temperature;
        const apparentTemp = tempInfo.apparentTemperature;
        const summary = tempInfo.summary;

        console.log(`It's currently ${temp} degrees and feels like ${apparentTemp} degrees. \nThe local summary is: ${summary}.`);

        return data.currently;
        
    }).catch(error => {
        if (error.code === 'ENOTFOUND') {
            throw new Error('Could not connect to MapRequest server');
        } else {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    });
};
```

In my app.js I have

```js
app.get('/weather', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.query.address) {
        return res.send({
            error: 'You must provide an address!'
        })
    }

    forecast.getWeather(req.query.address).then(function(data) {
         res.send(data);
    });
    next();
});
```

I get `Cannot read property then of undefined` error in the browser. I'm thinking that's because when the response is sent the promise hasn't resolved. The app.get is based on what's in the express docs so I think it might be to do with my `getWeather` function. How can I wait for the promise to resolve and then perform all the action?

Comment: add your export and import for the getWeather function, are you exporting the function directly?

Comment: why `then(({data})` why not `then((data) => {...})`

Comment: it's almost as if `forecast.getWeather` isn't actually using the `function getWeather` - is that possible? How is it that `function getWeather` becomes `forecast.getWether` ... also `I'm thinking that's because when the response is sent the promise hasn't resolved` no, a promise always has a `.then` method because that's how promises work

Comment: @JaromandaX probably wrong export and import statements.

Comment: but `forecast.getWeather` IS a function - otherwise the error would be something else :p @AZ_

Comment: ohh point :D @JaromandaX

Comment: I've exported the getWeather function and required it in the app.js as const forecast = require('.utils/weather') hence the forecast.getWeather. @AbhikChakraborty data is a destructured object, it was originally response.data.

Comment: your function getWeather() doesn't return promise, so i can't be used with then.

Comment: Also, have you exported that function? i think you need to use `export function getWeather(encodedAddress, units, language).....`

Comment: Hi @ravi, yep, I've exported the function. Thanks for pointing that out out getWeather not being a promise in itself. How do I get Express to wait until the function has a return value before sending a response?

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is how you're importing/exporting; could you please show that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the Express callback immediately after requesting the data, here:

```
forecast.getWeather(req.query.address).then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
});
next();
```

Try this:

```
forecast.getWeather(req.query.address).then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
    next();
});
```

As an aside, I would recommend `catch`-ing the error in your Express router and passing it to the Express error handler, that way the HTTP request will fail properly rather than just hanging:

```
forecast.getWeather(req.query.address).then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
    next();
}).catch(next);
```

The last line is shorthand for `}).catch(err => next(err));`.

Comment: I didn't even spot the next(). And I'm not sure he needs it. he is not implementing a middleware(no need to direct access request or response

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) or [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) npm package for promise.

Try this.

```js
const Promise = require('promise')

function getWeather(encodedAddress, units, language) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let geoKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        let geocodeURL = `http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=${geoKey}&location=${encodedAddress}`;

    axios.get(geocodeURL).then(({ data }) => {
        if (((data.results[0].locations[0].geocodeQualityCode.substring(2)).match(/X/g) || []).length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Unable to find that address')
        }
        const locationInfo = data.results[0].locations[0];
        const lat = locationInfo.latLng.lat;
        const lng = locationInfo.latLng.lng;

        console.log('Here\'s the weather for: ', locationInfo.street, locationInfo.adminArea5,
            locationInfo.adminArea4, locationInfo.adminArea1,
            locationInfo.postalCode);

        const weatherKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

        units = units ? `units=${units}` : 'auto';
        language = language ? `lang=${language}` : 'lang=en';

        const weatherURL = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${weatherKey}/${lat},${lng}?${units}&${language}`;
        axios.get(weatherURL).then(resolve).catch(reject);

    }).then(({ data }) => {
        const tempInfo = data.currently;
        const temp = tempInfo.temperature;
        const apparentTemp = tempInfo.apparentTemperature;
        const summary = tempInfo.summary;

        console.log(`It's currently ${temp} degrees and feels like ${apparentTemp} degrees. \nThe local summary is: ${summary}.`);

        resolve(data.currently);

    }).catch(error => {
        if (error.code === 'ENOTFOUND') {
            reject(new Error('Could not connect to MapRequest server'));
        } else {
            reject(Error(error.message));
        }
    });
});
};
```

Comment: Why would OP need a Promise library when the issue isn't a lack of Promise, it's that something returns `undefined` instead of a `Promise` hence it has no `.then`